# how do i send a local instance of a class as a parameter when starting a new activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I would like to send in a local instance of a class as a parameter to a new activity but i am not sure how to go about achieving this goal. Any help would be appreciated!

Example:

```
AnotherClass anotherClass = new AnotherClass();
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newActivity.class);
i.putExtra("test", anotherClass);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: is there any reason not to define that instance in another class rather than sending it ?

Comment: I want to send an instance of a class containing values to a child activity which uses those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by passing an object that implements the `Parcelable` interface and calling the `intent.putExtra("obj", objThatImplementsParcelable);` to send it it to the other Activity and retrieve it by

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras(); 
MyObject obj = bundle.getParcelable("obj");
```

You can find more information on how to do that on this [link](http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/).